# coalesce the other way around

Tags: mysql

Hi i have this scenario

**My Table**

```
 create table foo(
    id int,
    num int1,
    stage enum('a','b','c'),
    unique(id,stage)
);
```

**here are a snippets for data**

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`id`, `num`, `stage`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'a'),
(1, 2, 'b'),
(1, 3, 'c'),
(2, 1, 'a'),
(2, 2, 'b'),
(2, 3, 'c'),
(3, 1, 'a'),
(3, 2, 'b'),
(4, 1, 'a');
```

> > **Notes on table**
> >
> > *an id that has a state of c must have a prior state of a,b triggers no problem*

### query this as

[image: Heidisql output]

> I did this useing distinct with scalar correlated subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT
id, IFNULL((
SELECT num
FROM foo f
WHERE f.id = foo.id AND f.stage = 'a'),'') `a`, IFNULL((
SELECT num
FROM foo f
WHERE f.id = foo.id AND f.stage = 'b'),'') `b`, IFNULL((
SELECT num
FROM foo f
WHERE f.id = foo.id AND f.stage = 'c'),'') `c`
FROM foo
```

> > **[Bottom line]**
> >     I want a better fasten to do this

*thanks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   id,
         MAX(IF(stage = 'a', num, NULL)) AS `a`
         MAX(IF(stage = 'b', num, NULL)) AS `b`
         MAX(IF(stage = 'c', num, NULL)) AS `c`
FROM     foo
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, IF(a=0, '', a) a, IF(b=0, '', b) b, IF(c=0, '', c) c
FROM (SELECT id, SUM(IF(stage = 'a', num, '')) a, 
            SUM(IF(stage = 'b', num, '')) b, SUM(IF(stage = 'c', num, '')) c
    FROM foo GROUP BY id) AS A
```

Comment: @reply it works perfectly as expected but i'll choode eggyal's answer because **no subquery** is involved